# java: cannot find symbol. Как решить проблему?

Tags: java

Почему переменные **width** и **height** не передаются в **BufferedImage**?
Компилятор ругается на 15-ю строчку.

```
1     static File img = null;
2     static BufferedImage image = null;
3    public static void stegWrite(String filename){
4            img = new File(filename);
5            BufferedImage imgch = null;
6            try{
7                imgch = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
8                int width = imgch.getWidth(); //Width of the image
9                int height = imgch.getHeight(); //Height of the image
10            }catch(Exception e){
11                imgch = null;
12            }
13           long size = img.length(); //Size of the image
14            try{
15                image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
16              image = ImageIO.read(img);
17                System.out.println("Reading complete.");
18            }catch(IOException e){
19                System.out.println("Error: "+e);
20            }
21        }
```

Полный код ошибки -- https://sun9-7.userapi.com/c831308/v831308826/178550/guX8nDn5dPo.jpg

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: @margareq Откуда взялась переменная image в 13 и 14 строках?

Comment: Попробуй убери инициализацию переменных из блока try catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная объявленная внутри `try/catch` никогда не будут доступна вне конструкции. Читайте про область видимости локальных переменных.

Так будет правильнее:

```
static File img = null;
static BufferedImage image = null;

public static void stegWrite(String filename)
{
    img = new File(filename);
    BufferedImage imgch = null;

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    try
    {
        imgch = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        width = imgch.getWidth(); // Width of the image
        height = imgch.getHeight(); // Height of the image
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        imgch = null;
    }

    long size = img.length(); // Size of the image

    try
    {
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        image = ImageIO.read(img);
        System.out.println("Reading complete.");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

P.S. На мой взгляд `Eclipse` более информативна (из коробки) на всякого рода ошибки в отличии от `Intellij IDEA`. Из-за этого у вас и возникла проблема. `Eclipse` сразу подсветила ошибку с инициализацией переменных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваше решение мне помогло.